Long term probability
You perform the following process on the poisitive integers: you roll two ordinary dice, and advance with the sum of the values of the faces. What is the probability of landing on some position $n$ for sufficiently large $n$? Now, due to simulations I get that the answer is 1/7, which is basically, $1/\mathbb{E}[{\text{sum in each roll of the two dice}]}$. It intuitively makes sense: in each roll you advance 7 on average so you'll cover 1/7 of the positive integers. What is the rigorous proof of this?

I understand the argument , but nevertheless am surprised that the simulation confirms it. With a single die , I would of course have expected such a behaviour , but with two dices we have very different probabilities for the score we achieve. For example : If we land at the position two less of the target (why should this scenario be so unlikely) , then the chance to hit the target is just $\frac{1}{36}$

@Peter Yes and it actually works for any number of random generators (discrete) in any range (generators need not have the same range).

This is true, with some mild hypotheses, with the dice rolls replaced by any finite set of probabilities $p_1, \dots p_k$ of advancing $k$ steps at each iteration. Write $X$ for the corresponding random variable (so $\mathbb{P}(X = k) = p_k$) and write $\mathbb{P}(n)$ for the probability that the sum $X_1, X_1 + X_2, X_1 + X_2 + X_3, \dots $ eventually hits $n$.
The mild hypothesis we need is that the $\gcd$ of the set of values $X$ takes (with nonzero probability) is equal to $1$. Otherwise the set of values $X_1, X_1 + X_2, \dots $ takes is divisible by this $\gcd$, so there is no limiting probability $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(n)$.
Conditioning on the previous step immediately before hitting $n$ gives a linear recurrence
$$\mathbb{P}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \mathbb{P}(n - i)$$
with characteristic polynomial $p(t) = t^k - \sum_{i=1}^k p_i t^{k-i}$. This polynomial satisfies $p(1) = 0$ (since the probabilities $p_i$ sum to $1$) and, moreover, $1$ is the unique complex root of $p(t)$ of absolute value $\ge 1$; this is because if $|z| \ge 1$ is a root then
$$|z^k| = |z|^k = \left| \sum_{i=1}^k p_i z^{k-i} \right| \le \sum_{i=1}^k p_i |z^{k-1}| = |z|^{k-1}$$
which is a strict inequality if $|z| > 1$, and if $|z| = 1$ then the triangle inequality in the middle is an equality iff the $z^{k-i}$ all have the same angle, so $z \ge 0$ is a non-negative real, hence $z = 1$ (this is where we need to use that $\gcd = 1$ hypothesis; otherwise we get roots of unity here).
This means that a linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $p(t)$ eventually converges to a constant, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(n)$ exists. We can compute what constant this is by figuring out the initial conditions of $\mathbb{P}(n)$. The linear recurrence above continues to be valid for $n \le k$ provided that we interpret the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(n - i)$ to be zero if $n - i < 0$, and let's say we start at $0$, so $\mathbb{P}(0) = 1$. This is equivalent to the statement that the generating function of $\mathbb{P}(n)$ is
$$\boxed{ \sum_{n \ge 0} \mathbb{P}(n) t^n = \frac{1}{1 - \sum p_i t^i} }$$
(you can check this by expanding the RHS out as a geometric series and seeing that it gives the same result as repeatedly applying the recurrence, although probably a nicer argument is possible), in which case $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(n)$ is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(n) = \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{1 - t}{1 - \sum p_i t^i} = \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{1}{\sum i p_i t^{i-1}} = \boxed{ \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(X)} }$$
as expected, where in the second step we use l'Hopital's. This argument should actually generalize to the case that $X$ can take countably many values; in particular we still get that generating function identity and we still get the same estimate on the location of the poles of the generating function. If $\mathbb{E}(X) = \infty$ then the limiting probability is $0$.
